# Install SSL certificates purchased from an external provider

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, https, certificate

I have a site (www.ejemplo.com) hosted on an EC2 instance with Windows Server 2012 and I want to install SSL certificates that I bought through an external provider (Thawte). I do not know how to do it. I followed the steps of: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/es_es/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_server-certs.html
but I could not do it.

Comment: That guide is for using the ACM service which is used for adding SSL certificates to load balancers, CloudFront distributions, and API Gateway. If you are just using a single Windows EC2 instance then you need to find a guide/tutorial for installing the SSL certificates on a Windows server. The fact that the Windows server is running on AWS would be irrelevant.

Comment: Ahhh ok, but surely in AWS you have to make some configuration too. or not?

Comment: You would need to open port 443 in the security group assigned to the server, if you haven't already. That's about it. All the SSL configuration would happen on the actual server.